# How to make Web Application project a standalone with IIS Express and SQL Server Express?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, sql-server-2008, iis-express

How can I make Web Application project a standalone desktop application with IIS Express and SQL Server Express?

With "standalone" I mean clicking on an exe-file start my application (e.g. start.aspx in my browser). The whole application consists of lots of aspx-files which run in a browser.

NOW: I have my Web Application project running fine when pressing F5 in Visual Studio 2010.

MY AIM: I want to start this project on a local machine just as easy as it is in Visual Studio, but how could I do so?

Comment: I'm not sure that IIS Express was intended for use in this way, and if you want to make a standalone desktop application you are better off using SQL Server Compact Edition instead of SQL Server Express.

Comment: I think is very nice question, why the close ?

Comment: What do you mean "standalone"? You mean like a desktop application where there's a .exe file that gets launched and then the UI appears?

Comment: @Aristos I voted to close because its a very vague question which basically has the answer "Use IIS Express instead of IIS and SQL Compact Edition instead of SQL Server".

Comment: @John here is an example http://www.providesupport.com/screenshots/operator-console.html This application use some kind of html, and page render, gets data from internet etc... I do not know what limitation some can place, eg, can connect to the internet ? can run iis or any web server locally, can run sql express or any sql ?

Comment: @Kragen I edited my question, to make thinks clearer. Also I want to know **how** to use IIS Express to get a my application starting with one-click.

Comment: @Aristos I think it has to be IIS because of ASPX and ASPX.CS files. And it should be a Microsoft SQL Server, because lots of data is stored in a MDB-file.

Comment: @KB: with all due respect, it doesn't sound like you know much about ASP.NET development. Is there someone at work you can talk to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misunderstanding what happens when you press F5 in Visual Studio.

When you press F5, and if you're using the Visual Studio Development Server instead of IIS, that server is started up, and can serve requests for your application that come in on `localhost`. In any case, Visual Studio next starts your default browser and tells it to browse to your web application. The only application being launched on the desktop is your browser.

When your application is ready for other users to use, you will need to deploy it to a web server. Once it is deployed to the web server, users will be able to open their browser and browse to your application.

There is no simple way to package up a web server, database server, and your web application into a single .exe that a user can double-click.

Comment: I inherited the project from some student assistant. I don't know much about ASP. I'll try to grub though the MSDN help for Web Application Projects. But I found a website writing about MircoServers for Stand Alone Web Applications, see: http://code.roadsend.com/pcc-manual/Stand-Alone-Web-Applications-_0028MicroServer_0029.html . That made me hope, that not everything is lost...

Comment: My recommendation is to forget about it. It's a very unusual thing to do, and in fact, a very advanced thing to do.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Unfortunately this is not an option. I have to make this thing going.

Comment: @KB: good luck. Programmers with much more experience than you would fail to get this working. There's no standard way to do it, and you should make sure that whoever is asking you to do this knows that you _will_ be creating the mechanism to accomplish it, not just finding it out on Google.

Comment: Using the old cassini it was possible. As far as i know IISExpress need to be installed separately and cannot be used as a self-hosting service into your executable.

Answer (score 2):

i recommend you look into this product

http://ultidev.com/products/UWS-Cassini-Pro/Default.aspx

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to use SQL CE, which has a number of limitations, such as the inability to auto-increment identity type columns.

Comment: Why do I need to use SQL CE? Isn't MS SQL Server Express free either? See: http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/express.aspx

Comment: SQL CE does support auto inc (and Guid) keys. I'm using SqlCe4 but I'm almost sure 3.5 had them too.

Answer (score -1):

Why would you use IIS for a stand-alone desktop application? A web application is for the web. If you want desktop that look into WinForms of WPF. I doubt you will find any tools to do the conversion for you so you will have to make it a manual process. Just hope you have a well structured web app.

Unless of course, you mean to just access a local web application from your local machine IIS installation? If so, then just set up IIS like you would do on a server, assign yourself a port to the localhost to access the web application and then create a nice desktop shortcut that links to the correct URL

Comment: I want to use my application locally only on a local machine.

Comment: So what part are you struggling with? Do you know how to use IIS to host a website? Either way, the website will have to be run in a browser of some kind so the easiest way is a desktop shortcut to a webpage (your start.aspx page)

You could write a very basic WinForms application that just has a browser control to show the web app if you really need it to be an .exe file with no browser elements

Comment: I have no experience hosting websites with IIS. The application should be distributed on a CD or by download. The end-user should not struggle with configuring an IIS server, but only click on an exe (or someting similar) to be ready to work with the program. The web application project is very comprehensive, so I don't want to make big changes on it, like converting it to a WinForms app.

Comment: @KB: Maybe you should have thought about that before creating a comprehensive web application?

Comment: @KB: I really don't see how you got a far as you have done without thinking about how you are going to deploy it. You just need to bite the bullet and learn how to setup in IIS and make the best instruction manually you can to allow users to easily do it themselves. May be take a look at one-click publishing to help but you still need to install other software

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465337.aspx